# .closest() function is not working for inputs

Tags: javascript, closest

I have HTML like this in

```
<input type="text" class="q" placeholder="search nearby">
<input type="hidden" name="lat" class="lat" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="lon" class="lon" value="456">
<input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-go">
```

I want to get values of classes `lat/lon/q` by clicking on `btn-go`. I know we can do this using closest but i couldn't achieve this somehow.

My JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-go', function(){
        var lat_value = $(this).closest('input').find('.lat').val();
        var lon_value = $(this).closest('input').find('.lon').val();
        var q_value = $(this).closest('input').find('.q').val();

        alert(lat_value + lon_value + q_value);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `siblings`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-go', function() {
  var lat_value = $(this).siblings('.lat').val();
  var lon_value = $(this).siblings('.lon').val();
  var q_value = $(this).siblings('.q').val();

  alert(lat_value + lon_value + q_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="q" placeholder="search nearby">
<input type="hidden" name="lat" class="lat" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="lon" class="lon" value="456">
<input type="button" value="Go" class="btn btn-go btn-xs btn-primary b">
```

Comment: @Coffee - Glad to help you!